# setting IsEditable=false for item disables save/close button but not save button?

Tags: tridion

I developed a data extender class that acts on GetItem and CheckOutItem commands to do some business-specific validation to determine whether the user should have access to modify the item or not (basically if it's past the initial "author" task in workflow, no one can edit it. by default Tridion allows "reviewers" in workflow to edit the item, which is a no-no in our business).

I am relatively certain this worked at one point, but now does not. I'm exploring what might have changed, but I thought I'd ask here in case anyone has an idea.

If the item can't be modified, I'm setting the IsEditable attribute to false. This does in fact disable the Save and Close button and Save and New button, but for some reason the Save button is enabled. I don't quite understand why there could be a difference. (I'm looking to see if someone extended the save button somehow, but I don't see that being done). Any thoughts on how the Save button would enable when the others aren't?

thanks for any suggestions,

~Warner

```cs
public override XmlTextReader ProcessResponse(XmlTextReader reader, PipelineContext context)
{
    using (new Tridion.Logging.Tracer())
    {
        string command = context.Parameters["command"].ToString();
        if (command == CHECKOUT_COMMAND || command == GETITEM_COMMAND)
        {
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = ExtenderUtil.GetExtenderAsXmlDocument(reader);
            XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
            nsmgr.AddNamespace("tcm", Constants.TcmNamespace);
            try
            {
                //is this a page or component?
                XmlNode thisItemNode = null;
                thisItemNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//tcm:Component", nsmgr) ?? xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//tcm:Page", nsmgr);
                if (thisItemNode == null) return ExtenderUtil.GetExtenderAsXmlTextReader(xmlDoc);
                // need to impersonate system admin in order to get workflow version of item later
                Session sessionSystemAdmin = Util.SystemAdminSession;
                XmlAttribute idAttribute = thisItemNode.Attributes.GetNamedItem("ID") as XmlAttribute;
                //if ID attribute is null, we don't have the actual object being used (just a referenced item. so, we'll ignore it)
                if (idAttribute != null)
                {
                    string itemId = idAttribute.Value;
                    VersionedItem tridionObject = Util.ObtainValidTridionIdentifiableObject(sessionSystemAdmin, itemId) as VersionedItem;
                    //logic has been moved to separate method, just for maintainablility...
                    //the logic may change when workflow code is finished.
                    bool allowSave = IsItemValidForEdit(tridionObject, nsmgr);
                    if (!allowSave)
                    {
                        //not the WIP ("author") task... make item read-only
                        Logger.WriteVerbose("setting iseditable to false for item: " + itemId);
                        XmlAttribute isEditableAttribute = thisItemNode.Attributes.GetNamedItem("IsEditable") as XmlAttribute;
                        isEditableAttribute.Value = "false";
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Logger.WriteError("problem with get item data extender", ErrorCode.CMS_DATAEXTENDER_GETITEM_FAILURE, e);
            }
            return ExtenderUtil.GetExtenderAsXmlTextReader(xmlDoc);
        }
        else
        {
            return reader;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I expect that you should set the AllowedActions (too). But it's a matter of diving into the JavaScript code to find out.

Comment: Nice question, could we interest you in committing to the [Area 51 Tridion specific proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=gPujQMxthNCNn9xqeeO2NA2). Sign up with the same SO account if you have a moment.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, here's the XML I see for AllowedActions. any idea how to make sense of what this is telling me?
    <tcm:AllowedActions><tcm:Actions Allow="8402952" Deny="289522663" Managed="0" /></tcm:AllowedActions>

Comment: The Allowed Actions are a collection of Action values. If you look up the values in the API docs (e.g. the Core Service CHM), you will find all values. The it's a matter of deconstructing the value from the attribute above. E.g. 8402952 deconstructs to "FinishActivityAction, ViewAction, EditAction, SearchAction, RePublishAction, UnPublishAction, PublishAction, UnLocalizeAction, LocalizeAction, RollbackAction, HistoryListAction, UndoCheckOutAction, CheckInAction, CheckOutAction"
So removing CheckInAction (2) from that will likely disable the CheckIn button.

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen, that gives me something good to go on. Though it's not the checkin button that I'm after, it's the Save button. but, maybe disabling checkin will help me accomplish that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to **really** look over the entire solution and be absolutely positive that nobody snuck something in recently that messes with the Save button and is magically enabling it behind the scenes. I've re-edited the code to show how I initially had it. And it does work. It will disable the save, save/close, save/new buttons and make all fields disabled. I'm sorry that I wasted Frank's time. Hopefully having this here for historical purposes may come in handy for someone else with similar requirements in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the Tridion GUI probably bases the options it presents on the so-called Allowed Actions. This is a combination of the `Allow` and `Deny` attributes that are present in list-calls (if requested) and item XML.

So at the very least you will have to remove the CheckIn and Edit action from the `Allow` attribute (and probably add them to the `Deny` attribute). If you look at the Core Service documentation (or any other Tridion API documentation: these values haven't changed in a long time) you can find an Enum called `Actions` that hold the possible actions and their corresponding values. The `Allow` and `Deny` attributes are simply additions of these numbers.

The CheckIn action I mention is number `2`, Edit is `2048`.

---

***Update***:

I have a little command line program to [decode the AllowedActions](http://apps.vanpuffelen.net/tridion/allowedactions.html) for me. To celebrate your question, I quickly converted it into a web page that you can find [here](http://apps.vanpuffelen.net/tridion/allowedactions.html). The main work horse is below and shows both how you can decode the number and how you can manipulate it. In this case it's all subtraction, but you can just as easily add an allowed action by adding a number to it.

```js
var AllowedActionsEnum = {
    AbortAction:                134217728,
    ExecuteAction:               67108864,
    FinishProcessAction:         33554432,
    RestartActivityAction:       16777216,
    FinishActivityAction:         8388608,
    StartActivityAction:          4194304,
    BlueprintManagedAction:       2097152,
    WorkflowManagedAction:        1048576,
    PermissionManagedAction:       524288,
    EnableAction:                  131072,
    CopyAction:                     65536,
    CutAction:                      32768,
    DeleteAction:                   16384,
    ViewAction:                      8192,
    EditAction:                      2048,
    SearchAction:                    1024,
    RePublishAction:                  512,
    UnPublishAction:                  256,
    PublishAction:                    128,
    UnLocalizeAction:                  64,
    LocalizeAction:                    32,
    RollbackAction:                    16,
    HistoryListAction:                  8,
    UndoCheckOutAction:                 4,
    CheckInAction:                      2,
    CheckOutAction:                     1
};
function decode() {
    var original = left = parseInt(prompt('Specify Allow/Deny actions'));
    var msg = "";
    for (var action in AllowedActionsEnum) {
        if (left >= AllowedActionsEnum[action]) {
            msg += '\n' + action + ' ('+AllowedActionsEnum[action]+')';
            left -= AllowedActionsEnum[action];
        }
    }
    alert(original+msg);
}
```

Comment: Awesome. that has me oh so close now. but, must admit my C# noob-ness. I have the AllowedActions and can tell if it has a flag set, but I'm not sure how to modify the AllowedActions to clear that flag. I don't see any sort of method for that. or, do I have to convert to an int and start doing math?
Actions aActions = tridionObject.AllowedActions;
if (aActions.HasFlag(Actions.CheckIn))
                                        {
                                            //not sure what goes here...
                                        }

Comment: The Actions are a like a bit-mask, so you can simply add/subtract the value that you want to add/remove. I'll paste some JavaScript that I wrote up that does that.

Comment: much appreciated. I think it's gotten me really close, however, I was able to have it clear out the Edit flag, but not CheckIn. I edited the code above to show how I've modified it. am I doing the test wrong?

Comment: Frank, I think I'm doing what I should and it's not working. I even tried explicitly setting the allowed actions to only Actions.View and deny actions to most everything else, and it still enables the save button. could something else be running to override this?
<tcm:AllowedActions><tcm:Actions Allow="8192" Deny="238950519" Managed="0" /></tcm:AllowedActions>

Comment: Did you already look at the JavaScript code that handles those AllowedActions to see why it doesn't apply them?

Comment: I tried... however, I just found the REAL problem... and apparently I have to have a conversation with my buddy Nuno... I removed a customization of his and now the save button disappears properly. so, I'm really sorry that I wasted your time on this. it was highly educational, though. It may come in handy in the future.

Comment: We all learned some new things, I wrote a little tool, who said anything about wasting time?!?!? ;-)   It's a shame we couldn't get it solved here though.